# decode csv file in utf-8 (django + pandas)

Tags: python, django, pandas

My code generates a csv file, returns it to the browser. After downloading the file, all Russian words look like: РђР ± Р ° РєР ° РЅ ... encoding as if it doesn’t work. Tell me, please, how can I solve the problem?

```
dataCsv = data.to_csv(sep=';', header='True', decimal=',', encoding='utf-8')
response = HttpResponse(dataCsv, content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'

return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my settings file i'm insert

```
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'cp1251'
```

Views:

```
dataCsv = data.to_csv(sep=';', header='True', decimal=',', encoding='cp1251')
response = HttpResponse(dataCsv, content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use 'cp869 Codec' for Russian

check the link for more details:
https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an issue with UTF-8 and CSV, and I found a fix after much searching. I can't recall to credit the original, but what I did was add:

```
    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
```

after setting up the response. So you'd have:

```
response = HttpResponse(dataCsv, content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))

return response
```

From my understanding, this tells Excel "This is a UTF-8 encoded file".